# Angular 2 http get is not working, but i can see json response in postman

Tags: http, angular

I am trying to get a list of heroes from the backend where the backend is implemented using Sring MVC, Rest and added CORS(Cross-origin-resourc-sharing).

JSON Response:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Sai"},{"id":2,"name":"Ram"},{"id":11,"name":"Mr. Nice"},{"id":12,"name":"Narco"},{"id":13,"name":"Bombasto"},{"id":14,"name":"Celeritas"},{"id":15,"name":"Magneta"},{"id":16,"name":"RubberMan"},{"id":17,"name":"Dynama"},{"id":18,"name":"Dr IQ"},{"id":19,"name":"Magma"},{"id":20,"name":"Tornado"}]
```

So when I try to hit that url from postman and browser I am getting back the JSON, but when I am using in my front end code, its not giving me those objects

In the front end I am using angular 2 framework. so here is how I have implemented the code, please let me know whats the problem with this?

**Hero Service:**

```
export class HeroService {
        private heroUrl: string = "http://localhost:7001/springmvcrestfulwebservice/service/heroes/";
        constructor(private http:Http){
        }
       getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]>{
            //return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
            return this.http.get(this.heroUrl)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response=>response.json().data as Hero[])
                .catch(this.handleError);
        }
    }
```

**HeroesComponent:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {HeroService} from './hero.service';
import {Hero} from "./Hero";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    providers: [HeroService],
    selector: 'heroes',
    templateUrl: 'heroes.component.html'
})

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit{
    myHeroes: Hero[];
    constructor(private heroService: HeroService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getDataFromServer();
    }
    getDataFromServer():void{
        this.heroService.getHeroes()
            .then(
                myHeroes => this.myHeroes = myHeroes
            );
    }
}
```

Nothing is showing up in myHeroes. Please help me with this.

Comment: Maybe a typo or copy/paste thing, but you need a `=` within `private heroUrl: string "...";`

Comment: private heroUrl: string = "http://localhost:7001/springmvcrestfulwebservice/service/heroes/";

Comment: this is how it looks in my original code, yes its a typo

Comment: Do you see the response in the network tab in chrome dev tools?

Comment: Have you included the HTTP provider in your application?

Comment: yes i have included http provider in my app.module.ts file.

Comment: @NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
      JsonpModule
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,
  HeroesComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: @joshvito, no i cant see anything my network in dev tools

Comment: i think.it does not access `getDataFromServer` from `ngOnInit` method.Can you try inserting `console.log` into `getDataFromServer`.

Comment: I kept this console statement in the getDataFromServer method, its showing up in the developer tools console, but I cant see the "Get" call in networks tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rewrite your service to return an Observable and convert to a Promise in the Component does the get call show up in the network tab?

```
//Hero Service
 getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]>{
            return this.http.get(this.heroUrl)
                .map(response => response.json() as Hero[])
                .catch(this.handleError);
        }

//Hero Component
this.heroService.getHeroes()
  .toPromise()            
  .then(
    myHeroes => this.myHeroes = myHeroes
  );
```

Comment: No, now also I cant see the XHR request in networks tab and I have edited the code as you shown above

Comment: Hey, I am sorry, I can see the call now, may be before I was looking at a wrong window before, here is the response that I am getting for that get call..

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:7001/springmvcrestfulwebservice/service/heroes/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:7001
Response Headers
view source

Comment: but this data is not mapping to my heroes as what I am expecting! can you help me out with this please..

Comment: when I am trying to put a console.log(this.myHeroes) at the end of the getDataFromServer(), its giving me undefined